# "method incompatible with supertype" when using *args: Any

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, abc

I've been working on a class that utilises abstract methods. However, I'm getting a mypy error for overwriting the function declaration in each child class. Could someone please explain to me how I can achieve the same effects, whilst also obeying mypy's desires.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any

class Base(ABC):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
       # general init stuff for all classes...
       self.myAbstractMethod(*args, **kwargs)

    @abstractmethod
    def myAbstractMethod(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        pass

class Child1(Base):
    def myAbstractMethod(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
        print(x + y)

class Child2(Base):
    def myAbstractMethod(self, a: str) -> None:
        print(a)

Child1(1, 2)
Child2('hello stackoverflow')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding abstract methods in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008237/overriding-abstract-methods-in-python)

Comment: i think this is simply a case where `Child1` and `Child2` shouldn't be implementations of a common interface. I think you're using the wrong design